# Локализация проекта в Android Studio

Tags: android, локализация

Настало время локализации. Нужно найти все русские символы по проекту, вынести в strings.xml и добавить ссылки. Догадываюсь, что найти можно с использованием regExp, но возможно есть готовые инструменты для автоматической локализации или инструменты самой AndroidStudio?

Answer (score 10):

Об этом надо было думать сразу, а не искать какие то символы теперь. Инструмента, комплексно перегоняющего хардкорные строки в строковые ресурсы в *Android Studio* нет.

Если открыть `strings.xml` там вверху будет кнопка <kbd>Open Editor</kbd> - это инструмент локализации - *Translation Editor*:

[image: screen]

Глобус - добавить язык.
Плюс - добавить строковый ресурс.

Так же доступ к этому инструменту можно получить из визуального редактора разметки любого лэйаута:

[image: screen]

Если строки у вас хардкорные (прописанные в коде, а не в ресурсах `strings.xml`), то для начала нужно перенести ВСЕ строки в проекте в этот самый `strings.xml`, а потом уже локализовать.
На любой хардкорной строке, как в разметке, так и в коде, *Android Studio* отмечает предупреждение желтой лампочкой и предлагает перенести строку в ресурсы - *Extract String Resource*. Такую операцию нужно будет проделать для КАЖДОЙ хардкорной строки, поэтому этим и нужно заниматься сразу, в процессе написания кода, а не потом вдруг, когда уже сотни строк захардкорено:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]