# Как реализовать поддержку нескольких языков в приложений?

Tags: android

Объясните  новичку ,как реализовать поддержку нескольких языков в приложений , желательно с пошаговой инструкцией.

Comment: в смысле чтобы юзер сам определял язык или это за него делало приложение во главе с системой?

Answer (score 9):

Это локализация когда язык приложения соответствует языку системы

Щёлкаем правой кнопкой мыши на папке res и выбираем New | Android resource directory. В диалоговом окне в левой части Available qualifiers: выбираем пункт Locale и переносим его в правую часть Chosen qualifiers: с помощью кнопки с двумя стрелками вправо. В появившейся третьей колонке выбираем нужные языки, например, русский. Вы увидите, что в поле Directory name автоматически появится нужное название папки. Дополнительно вы можете указать и регион в колонке Specific Region Only
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Изменим его содержание.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Локализованное приложение</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Здравствуй, Мир!</string>
</resources>
```

В английской версии им соответствуют ресурсы

```
<string name="app_name">Locale Application</string>
<string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
```

Вот еще [Локализация проекта в Android Studio](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/452954/%D0%9B%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-android-studio)