# Локализация приложения или отдельных строк

Tags: android, locale

Вот кусочек кода. Хочу что бы строка `title("Latest")` переводилась на разные языки.

```
models.add(
        new NavigationTabBar.Model.Builder(
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_home),
                Color.parseColor(colors[1]))
                .title("Latest")
                .build()
);
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/452963/177345

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала передавайте ссылку на String пункт:

`.title(R.string.latest)`

Затем по директории `Res` правой кнопкой мыши и:

`Res > New > Android Resource Directory`. В окошке `Available qualifiers` кликните на `locale` меж двух окошек есть `>>` кликните туда, и в правом окошке `Chosen qulifiers` появятся языки. Выбриаете нужный язык, выбираете нужный регион, например Турция, и жмете `OK`. В директории `Res` появится папка `values-tr-rTR` помещаете в неё разметку `string.xml` из папки `values` и в ней текст должен быть на турецком. Таким образом, в двух разных директориях (в `values` и `values-tr-rTR`) у вас будут `string.xml`. Их пункты должны быть одинаковыми, а содержание пунктов на соответствующих языках. И теперь, когда язык системы устройства будет турецким, `title(R.string.latest)` будет брать текст из `values-tr-rTR`. И так со всеми языками соответственно.

**UPD**

И вызывайте `getString`: `getString(R.string.latest)`

Comment: в андроид студио есть [редактор локализаций (Translation Editor)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/452963/177345), работать через который намного удобнее

Comment: @pavlofff перфекто)

Comment: @McDaggen спасибо за подробный ответ. Я так и ранее пробовал title(R.string.latest) . Само приложение (основной текст) перевел давно. У меня остались проблемы с некоторыми элементами. Посмотрите Скриншот http://prntscr.com/l2zn36 Студио выдает ошибку title (java.lang.String) in Builder cannot be applied to (int)

Comment: Тогда попробуйте получить строку. getString(R.string.latest). Если используете вызов таббара не в активити, нужно будет вызывать через контекст

Comment: @McDaggen  ,спасибо теперь все  работает!